# Ranking items according to date and amount in SQL

Tags: sql, rank

I have the following lines for the same item:

```
ID  START_DATE  END_DATE    AMOUNT  RANK    MIN START DATE
1   11/04/2012  24/10/2012  6   2   11/04/2012
1   25/10/2012  09/12/2012  9   1   25/10/2012
1   10/12/2012  10/04/2013  9   1   25/10/2012
1   11/04/2013  17/06/2014  9   1   25/10/2012
1   15/09/2019  10/10/2019  6   2   11/04/2012
```

what i want is to get the min start date according to each item, the problem is that I have the amount 6 on two different periods which confuses my ranking.
What I expect to have is

```
ID  START_DATE  END_DATE    AMOUNT  RANK    MIN START DATE
1   11/04/2012  24/10/2012  6   2   11/04/2012
1   25/10/2012  09/12/2012  9   1   25/10/2012
1   10/12/2012  10/04/2013  9   1   25/10/2012
1   11/04/2013  17/06/2014  9   1   25/10/2012
1   15/09/2019  10/10/2019  6   3   15/09/2019
```

Any tips ?
Thanks

Comment: need to know the rules which govern your ranking as it stands it's hard to discern what you're doing ranking by the min start date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, it can be solved using `row_number` function to define groups for the consecutive amount values as the following:

```
SELECT ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, AMOUNT,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY GRP) AS RANK,
       MIN(START_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY GRP) AS MIN_START_DATE
FROM
  (
    SELECT ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, AMOUNT,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY START_DATE) -
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, AMOUNT ORDER BY START_DATE) GRP
    FROM table_name
  ) T
 ORDER BY START_DATE
```

The output of this query:

```
ID  START_DATE  END_DATE    AMOUNT  RANK    MIN_START_DATE
1   2012-04-11  2012-10-24  6       1       2012-04-11
1   2012-10-25  2012-12-09  9       2       2012-10-25
1   2012-12-10  2013-04-10  9       2       2012-10-25
1   2013-04-11  2014-06-17  9       2       2012-10-25
1   2019-09-15  2019-10-10  6       3       2019-09-15
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/VjXW7JyC).